# Customize Appexchange app

Tags: apex, visualforce, appexchange

Can i customize appexchange app. There is a search bar in one of the custom object tab.There is only search by object name i want to add search by field like custom object status field,created date,last modified field,City .Can i have this customization.

The custom object tab runs a visualforce page which have some controller. As they are managed pakages i dont think i can edit them. Can i have above functionality added somehow in search bar of that object tab.

Answer (score 0):

With managed package , the package owner has ability to whether lock the code completely or expose few interfaces for the subscriber to implement or making class as global to expose the class to subscriber .

In case the code is locked ,you cannot edit controller and you are blocked at this point to do anything .You may request the actual owner of the code to add those functionality for you